# adsense banners (iframes) scrolling OVER fixed divs

Tags: iframe, adsense, fixed

I have one `div` with `position:fixed 0`; that stays on the top of the browser window even when I scroll down.
The problem is the adsense banners (iframes) that are out of the fixed div (thus in the main site's content div that should appear under), when I scroll down, they go OVER the fixed div and not below it.
I tried to apply a `clear: both` and `z-index` to both elements but nothing changed.
Can't iframe not go below fixed elements?

thank you

Comment: are you sure this practice isn't against the ToS rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have proper positioning for `z-index` to work. Makes sure the iframe container is `position:relative` or `position:absolute`